# Не работает phpcs

Tags: php, windows, symfony, openserver

Дано: ОС windows 10, на системном диске C стоит OpenServer, для которого в настройках указано, что корневая папка доменов на другом диске - D. Через composer на диске C установлен phpcodesniffer. Т.е. сервер на одном диске, проект - на другом. В phpStorm указан path для phpcs: C:\Users\UserXYZ\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs.bat. Когда начинаешь работать в шторме, начинает постоянно вылазить ошибка:

```
phpcs: 
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
There are no commands defined in the "C" namespace
```

Я так понимаю, phpcs считает, что C (на самом деле, название диска) - это namespace, не находит такой namespace и падает.

Не нашел пока, как это лечится, буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Попробуй опустить букву и вначале оставить только слеш

Comment: Попробовал. Получился путь \Users\UserXYZ\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin\phpcs.bat. Ошибка та же, ничего не изменилось